# Is there a "safe" way to modify HTML with Python, and write it to file again?

Tags: python, html, flask, escaping, jinja2

I'm making a blog with Flask/Jinja, and I'm storing each blog's html content into a .json file (for specific needs). I noticed that when reading the html content into Python with:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

everything looks fine when I print the original data. However, when I modify and extract parts of the html using Python, all of the sudden, the newlines are replaced by \n, and the ' are replaced by \' which breaks everything when served as html again (or when dumped into a .json file to be opened later). I know I can replace the "\n" pretty easily, but I'm curious as to why Python does that, and if there's a "safe" way to handle html, edit it, and then write it out to file again?

Comment: No, Python doesn't do that. My guess is that you are `print`ing the string in one case, seeing its representation in the latter. The representation of a string is intended to show you unambiguously what's actually in it and so it uses escape codes for many characters *for display.* Of course, this is just a guess since you didn't show any of the code you're using to "modify and extract."

Comment: if you want to edit HTML, you should look at libraries like beautifulsoup
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: @kindall, you are correct, I tried 'print(repr(html_str))' with the first case, and indeed it had escaped many characters as well. Is there a best practice to modify html with Python and serve it back to an html templating module like Flask so line breaks don't get rendered as \n?